# How to use de psql command line from docker typing psql on host terminal?

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

Is there a way to use the psql command from docker on my terminal host?
I am using a postgresql 11 container, but to access psql I have to install a postgres on the host machine.

My docker file has just one line:

```
FROM postgres:11
```

How can I use the command above without install postgresql on host machine:

```
psql -c "CREATE DATABASE test_db WITH encoding 'UTF-8'" -h localhost -U postgres
```

I will use this command on bash scripts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`psql` is already in the container, so you don't need to install it. You can use following command to invoke psql

```
docker exec <<container name>> psql -c "CREATE DATABASE test_db WITH encoding 'UTF-8'" -h localhost -d <<database>> -U <<user>>
```

The database and user will depend on the environment variables `POSTGRES_DB` and `POSTGRES_USER` that you had configured when you ware starting the container